# Allow Multiple Content Items in Orchard CMS

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

How can I add the "Allow multiple content items" option to a custom content part that I created?

I have created my content part module call "howtostep". The content part is just two string fields called image and instruction. The content part will be part of a content item called "How To" The content item must have 1 or more how to steps in it so I want to have N number of content parts.

What do I need to do to "Allow multiple content items"? Is there a sample somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `Tutorial` content type with a content picker field configured to allow for multiple items. 
Then you can create a new tutorial, and add multiple steps to it.